# What obfuscator do this?

Tags: disassembly, deobfuscation

So, first if i try to use DnSpy all the methods are empty and some of them returns decompiler exceptions like

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative number required. (Parameter 'length')
   at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)
   at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Array destinationArray, Int32 length)
   at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.ILAst.ILAstBuilder.StackSlot.ModifyStack(StackSlot[] stack, Int32 popCount, Int32 pushCount, ByteCode pushDefinition) in D:\a\dnSpy\dnSpy\Extensions\ILSpy.Decompiler\ICSharpCode.Decompiler\ICSharpCode.Decompiler\ILAst\ILAstBuilder.cs:line 48
   at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.ILAst.ILAstBuilder.StackAnalysis(MethodDef methodDef) in D:\a\dnSpy\dnSpy\Extensions\ILSpy.Decompiler\ICSharpCode.Decompiler\ICSharpCode.Decompiler\ILAst\ILAstBuilder.cs:line 387
```

If i try to reference it in a vs project and access the namespace it doens't exists and it don't appear on the objects explorer, i tried using de4dot and it returns Detected Unknown Deobfuscator, also tried using a ConfuserEx deobfuscator but no success too, it always stop when trying to access the body of the methods that is always null, any ideas ?

Comment: Just a guess: do you try to decompile DLL files from an iOS Xamarin app?

Comment: @Robert No, it's a dll from a game mod